# swift - Navigation Bar Title Position

Tags: swift, xcode

I am wondering how to bring the title to the center again.

I have a search button on the right side, and when you click it, a search box will appear.
The title is being moved to the left, but when I close the search box, the title is not going back to it's original location.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Z6F.png)

You can see the on the third part, the title does not go back to the center.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit:
Here is the code:

```
func searchBtn(){
    searchBars.hidden = false
    search = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBars)
    var cancel = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelSearch))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [cancel,search]
    searchBars.becomeFirstResponder()
}
func cancelSearch(){

    searchBars.hidden = true
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: #selector(searchBtn))
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `searchBar` view instead of hiding it?

Comment: @Nucl3ic - yes, tried `searchBars.removeFromSuperview()` but still no luck